# Thinking Sphinx configuration fails - cannot connect to mysql through socket, despite socket existing!

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

When I run rake ts:conf, I get "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)"

This socket file does exist.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that part of my app was looking for /mysql.sock, and part for /mysqld.sock. I wound up just symlinking one to the other.